# Can Linux tell from the command line whether a monitor is connected?

Tags: linux, command-line, display

I would like to be able to tell, from the command line, whether a monitor is connected to a computer (so I can decide from a script whether X should be running or not).  How can I do that?

I can't depend on X's presence, so that rules out anything that relies on a valid X display, like `xrandr`.  I've found [`ddccontrol`](http://ddccontrol.sourceforge.net/), but its output is multi-line and not trivial to parse.  (It does tell me that the information is theoretically available in the way I want).  Is there a more script-friendly program that can tell me whether a monitor is connected to the system?

Most of the systems on which I would want to run this are running Fedora 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this on fedora 20, (only on Ubuntu 13.04), but the theory in my head is sound.

You could try using read-edid (http://www.polypux.org/projects/read-edid/)

Which should give you a XF86-compatible modeline.. Which you can parse.

So that *might* work.  Perhaps it's even easier and you could just check the exit code.

```
$ sudo get-edid > edid
get-edid: get-edid version 2.0.0

    Performing real mode VBE call
    Interrupt 0x10 ax=0x4f00 bx=0x0 cx=0x0
    Function supported
    Call successful

    VBE version 300
    VBE string at 0x11100 "NVIDIA"

VBE/DDC service about to be called
    Report DDC capabilities

    Performing real mode VBE call
    Interrupt 0x10 ax=0x4f15 bx=0x0 cx=0x0
    Function supported
    Call successful

    Monitor and video card combination does not support DDC1 transfers
    Monitor and video card combination supports DDC2 transfers
    0 seconds per 128 byte EDID block transfer
    Screen is not blanked during DDC transfer

Reading next EDID block

VBE/DDC service about to be called
    Read EDID

    Performing real mode VBE call
    Interrupt 0x10 ax=0x4f15 bx=0x1 cx=0x0
    Function supported
    Call failed

The EDID data should not be trusted as the VBE call failed
EDID claims 255 more blocks left
EDID blocks left is wrong.
Your EDID is probably invalid.
tom@tom:~$ parse-edid < edid 
parse-edid: parse-edid version 2.0.0
parse-edid: EDID checksum failed - data is corrupt. Continuing anyway.
parse-edid: first bytes don't match EDID version 1 header
parse-edid: do not trust output (if any).

    # EDID version 255 revision 255
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "___:ffff"
    VendorName "___"
    ModelName "___:ffff"
    # DPMS capabilities: Active off:yes  Suspend:yes  Standby:yes

    Mode    "4095x4095" # vfreq 9.770Hz, hfreq 80.018kHz
        DotClock    655.350000
        HTimings    4095 4350 4605 8190
        VTimings    4095 4158 4221 8190
        Flags   "Interlace" "+HSync" "+VSync"
    EndMode
    Mode    "4095x4095" # vfreq 9.770Hz, hfreq 80.018kHz
        DotClock    655.350000
        HTimings    4095 4350 4605 8190
        VTimings    4095 4158 4221 8190
        Flags   "Interlace" "+HSync" "+VSync"
    EndMode
    Mode    "4095x4095" # vfreq 9.770Hz, hfreq 80.018kHz
        DotClock    655.350000
        HTimings    4095 4350 4605 8190
        VTimings    4095 4158 4221 8190
        Flags   "Interlace" "+HSync" "+VSync"
    EndMode
    Mode    "4095x4095" # vfreq 9.770Hz, hfreq 80.018kHz
        DotClock    655.350000
        HTimings    4095 4350 4605 8190
        VTimings    4095 4158 4221 8190
        Flags   "Interlace" "+HSync" "+VSync"
    EndMode
EndSection
```

Comment: And if it's not one thing it's another...  I can just run `get-edid >/dev/null` and check its return code ...except that the targetted SELinux policy prevents `get-edid` from running because it tries to mmap /dev/mem.  I'm going to leave this question open for a bit to see if there are any other solutions offered.

Comment: Can you disable SELinux for get-edid?

Comment: There are Ways.  I even know roughly what I'd need to do to make it work.  I just don't want to go hacking SELinux policies if I don't have to.

Answer (score 2):

You can list info such as currently connected or "known" displays using `xrandr`:

```
# list all known monitors
xrandr --listmonitors --verbose

# list active monitors
xrandr --listactivemonitors
```

With a bit of grepping and such this would work. It's worth looking at the `man` pages to see if there is even better functionality for you use case.

**This is what I've found to be most useful for a script**

```
xrandr | grep " connected " # =>
  # eDP-1
  # HDMI-1 # <-- the monitor I want to detect

# AND -- to check if `HDMI-1` is connected
xrandr | grep " connected " | awk '{ print$1 }' | grep HDMI-1

# store connection status in a var
$hdmi_connection=$(xrandr | grep " connected " | awk '{ print$1 }' | grep HDMI-1)
```

Comment: I noted in the question, "I can't depend on X's presence, so that rules out anything that relies on a valid X display, like `xrandr`."